# Need to return null as response in weblogic 12c that uses jackson json provider

Tags: java, oracle, jackson, jax-rs, weblogic12c

In my weblogic 11g to 12c migrated java application, my API endpoint is

```
\`@GET
@Path("/scheme/id/{Id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List\<Scheme\> getSchemesById(@PathParam("Id") String id){
List\<Scheme\> list =  new List\<Scheme\>;

    return list;

}
\`
```

This returns {} if the list is empty. This list has some child objects that returns null, these nulls and empty object where removed from json response through ObjectMapper mapper properties(Look at the below properties).

mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

So that the response

```
\`{
"abc" : null, //null object
"xyz" : {}    // empty object

    .
    .

}\`
```

becomes {}. But instead of getting this {}, I need null to be the response for this parent object list. Guide me in getting the required response. This application supports both jersey 1 & jersey 2. Thank you.

I tried with Resource Context ObjectMapper properties like

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);  
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

also included
`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)` for list object getter methods.

Also I tried with a customized null serializer to check for null and to write null through jsongenerator as like below

`if (isFullOfNulls(value)) {     generator.writeStartObject();     generator.writeString("null");     generator.writeEndObject(); }`
isFullOfNulls() - checks for null at all the properties and child properties.